# Save a variable into a macro name and use it in many macro function

Tags: c, macros

I want to save a parameter into a macro name  and then use it into another macro function.

I m looking for something like that

```
#define MACRO1(X) MACRO_NAME = X

#define MACRO2(Y) Y = MACRO_NAME;

1int main()
{
    int a = 2, b;

    MACRO1(a);
    ...
    MACRO2(b)

}
```

Is it possible to do it ? and what the correct way to do it?

The code I gave above is just an example of what I want

Comment: The question that comes to mind is: why? Could you show a realistic use-case for this to explain what you're trying to do better?

Comment: No, this is thankfully impossible, and there is no correct way to do it. This is the worst kind of macro-abuse.

Answer (score 1):

The pre-processor only does textual replacements, it doesn't "run" the code. All it does is transform the code according to the defined macros (and `#include` directives and so on), and then hand it on to the compiler.

Your above example would mean that the compiler would see:

```
int a = 2, b;

MACRO_NAME = a;
...
b = MACRO_NAME;
```

This won't build, since there is no variable called `MACRO_NAME`. Your question is a bit unclear, you should clarify what it is you want to do, and why.

Comment: I want that the pre-processor does textual replacement for MACRO_NAME in all places is called and The MACRO_NAME value is assigned into another macro

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to change the code in following way. Declare MACRO_NAME an int variable; so inline replacement to first macro call will plce the code like "MACRO_NAME=a" and it will compile with no problem.

```
 #define MACRO1(X) MACRO_NAME = X
 #define MACRO2(Y) Y = MACRO_NAME;

 int main() {
    int a = 2, b;
    int MACRO_NAME;
    MACRO1(a);
    MACRO2(b)
}
```